# How to get Element by both ID and value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to get an element with both id and value? These are my elements. I want to disable these 3 radio buttons.

```
 <input id="selectedAnswerIDforQ15" name="selectedAnswerIDforQ15" type="radio" value="78" />

 <input id="selectedAnswerIDforQ15" name="selectedAnswerIDforQ15" type="radio" value="79" />

 <input id="selectedAnswerIDforQ15" name="selectedAnswerIDforQ15" type="radio" value="80" />
```

What I did is like below:

```
 document.getElementById("selectedAnswerIDforQ15").getElementByValue("78").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("selectedAnswerIDforQ15").getElementByValue("79").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("selectedAnswerIDforQ15").getElementByValue("80").disabled = true;
```

But this is not working. The Ids are same for all the three radio buttons.

If I just use `document.getElementById("selectedAnswerIDforQ15").disabled = true` It will only disable the first radio button. So I need a combination of both Id and Value. Please help.

Comment: Use class instead of id, and select items with getElementsByClassName, or querySelectorAll.

Comment: You cannot have duplicated `id` values, you can use: `selectedAnswerIDforQ15_78`, `selectedAnswerIDforQ15_79` and `selectedAnswerIDforQ15_80` for each input.

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
 $("input[name='selectedAnswerIDforQ15'][value='78']").attr('disabled', disabled');
 $("input[name='selectedAnswerIDforQ15'][value='79']").attr('disabled', disabled');
 $("input[name='selectedAnswerIDforQ15'][value='80']").attr('disabled', disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple elements with the same ID as IDs are specific to one element.

You need to use a class instead that way you can selector all of them, I'll use `.foo`.

**You can either do some like this**

Selecting your inputs

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("foo");
```

Then you'll need to iterate over the elements that your class is applied on.

```
for(var i =0; inputElements.length > i; i++){

}
```

Inside of that loop you'll find with element has the values you want and we'll select it and use `setAttribute()` to disable it.

```
for(var i =0; inputElements.length > i; i++){
    if(inputElements[i].value == "78" || inputElement[i].value == "79" || inputElements[i].value == "80"){
            inputElements[i].setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

**Or you can do something like this**

```
document.querySelector(".foo[value=78]").setAttribute("disabled", true);
document.querySelector(".foo[value=79]").setAttribute("disabled", true);
document.querySelector(".foo[value=80]").setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".foo[value=78]").setAttribute("disabled", true);` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Select by value (modern browsers):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[value=something]");
```

Select by id:

```
document.getElementById("someid");
```

Multiple elements with the same id on the same page is invalid `html`. You should use your ViewModel to strongly type unique ids and names for the radiobuttons, and never hard code string values.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same ids for each input, but still you can use following method:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll("[id='selectedAnswerIDforQ15']");
var values = ['78', '79'];
for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) 
    if (values.indexOf(elms[i].value) > -1)
        elms[i].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```